# MSB4018 Task Failed Unexpectedly when I run a blazor web app solution

Tags: compiler-errors, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Recently I try make my web pages with blazor webassembly because I want to make my web page more interactives, but when I run the solution, VS throw me the error "MSB4018 Task Failed Unexpectedly" and I try to create an other solution but the error ever appear, and I don't khow who how I can fix it,

I Google it
I search in the Microsoft Documentation
I create a lots of solutions but never change

Comment: Stack Overflow en español:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: My first guess would be that you are missing visual studio components to build your solution. First place I would look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visit the following link to get a solution
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-msb4018-the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed/559252